# firefox same origin policy turned off but jquery won't let me access iframe contents

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm doing some quick mashup and disabled the single origin policy in firefox by

about:config

and then set security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false

however when I try to access the DOM of another domain that is loaded in the iframe I get permission denied from jquery but not the browser.

how can i bypass this? not use jquery at all?

Answer (score 0):

Read MySQL documentation [Substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) section carefully. You get the answer to your question.